# CSS No Envio de Email JSP

Tags: java, email

Existe uma maneira para que eu possa enviar um e-mail pelo java usando inclusive css?
Para conseguir enviar o corpo formatado, eu consigo, mas eu gostaria de colocar bootstrap no conteúdo do email

```
          //Criando a Multipart
          Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

          //criando a primeira parte da mensagem
          MimeBodyPart attachment0 = new MimeBodyPart();
          //configurando o corpodamensagem com o mime type
          attachment0.setContent(corpoDaMensagem, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");


          //adicionando na multipart
          multipart.addBodyPart(attachment0);




          message.setContent(multipart);
```

Existem como?

Agradeço

Comment: lembrando que o bootstrap estou usando CDN

Comment: Geralmente pra este tipo de situação incluo o css inline mesmo! Não sei se é uma má prática! Mas no meu caso (situações bem específicas mesmo, tipo cores, tamanhos de fonte, etc) sempre funcionou

Comment: Pois é, estou fazendo isso por enquanto.